# Why do I draw a ellipse in grid will be blocked?

Tags: wpf

It's a WPF Program.
I draw a ellipse by c# code, then insert to grid's Children.
It's located at TreeViewItem.

I just see the part of ellipse at the front has be convert by lengthConverter.

xmal style:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"
           TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="1,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <converters:LeftMarginMultiplierConverter Length="19" x:Key="lengthConverter" />
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border Name="Bd"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid Name="Gd" Margin="{Binding Converter={StaticResource lengthConverter},
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="19" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                                              Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle2}"
                                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                              ClickMode="Press"/>

                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                                 Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                                 Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="HasHeader"
                                           Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Property="Width"
                                           Value="Auto"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                                    Property="MinWidth"
                                    Value="75"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="HasHeader"
                                           Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Property="Height"
                                           Value="Auto"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                                    Property="MinHeight"
                                    Value="19"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" 
                                    Property="Background" 
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                                    Property="Background"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                           Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive"
                                           Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                                    Property="Background"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                 Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

C# code:

```
    var item = sender as TreeViewItem;
    if (item.Items.Count > 0) return;
    var controlTemplate = item.Template as ControlTemplate;
    var grid=controlTemplate.FindName("Gd",item) as Grid;
    var p = args.GetPosition((IInputElement)item);
    var elli = new Ellipse
    {
        Width = 0,
        Height = 0,
        Fill = Brushes.White,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        Opacity = .6
    };
    grid.Children.Insert(0,elli);
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400)));
    animation.Completed += (s, e1) =>
    {
        grid.Children.Remove(elli);
    };
    elli.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation);
    elli.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, new DoubleAnimation(600, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400))));
    elli.BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, new DoubleAnimation(600, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400))));
    elli.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, new ThicknessAnimation(new Thickness(p.X, p.Y, 0, 0), new Thickness(p.X - 300, p.Y - 300, 0, 0), new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400))));
```

Comment: You haven't provide enough for anyone to figure this out.  The C# code is in some handler.  Which handler?  The "args" variable is undefined.   In the XAML "LeftMarginMultiplierConverter" is undefined.  You will need to either simplify or provide more to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I insert the ellipse in first column of the grid.  I set the column to solve it.